# Converting a long string into evenly split indexes in an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to convert the string:
`"Stack_Overflow"` 
to an array that's split by a predetermined amount of characters (say 5 characters):

`result = ["Stack", "_Over", "flow"]`

If there's nothing that can do that cleanly, I can make a loop that can do it for me as long as I could do something even more basic such as have an array like:

`["S", "t", "a", "c", "k"]`

And turn it into:

`["Stack"]`

I know how to combine the array using the `Array#join` method, but this turns it into an string. And using the `<<` operator will simply add an extra element, and I need to shovel into the SAME element. And `Array#flatten` won't work exactly like changing the index value itself either. Maybe if I could `String#split` the string to begin with, I could convert it then. But the `split` method wants to see a pattern/character to indicate a split, and it needs to simply be a number of characters. So I'm a bit at a loss from my research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be done with [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
"Stack_Overflow".scan(/.{1,5}/)
#=> ["Stack", "_Over", "flow"]
```

Chance the `5` to whatever predetermined amount of characters you want.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer @spickermann's use of a regex, but here's another way that uses  two enumerators to avoid the creation of temporary arrays:

```
str = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times."

str.each_char.each_slice(5).map(&:join)
  # => ["It wa", "s the", " best", " of t", "imes,", " it w",
  #     "as th", "e wor", "st of", " time", "s."]
```